# If two distributions are sufficiently close to each other, how is it possible for the difference between them to be statistically significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution, p-value, effect-size

As I understand it, p-values are derived from a test statistic, which measures how unlikely it is that we would get those data, *assuming the null hypothesis is true.*

But if this is the case, would it not be impossible to detect a statistically significant difference *if the means of the two distributions are close enough?*

[image]

For instance, if an effect size is considered small, how could it ever be the case that the mean of the blue distribution would ever reach a p-value of p < .05? I know conceptually that the higher the N, the lower the p-value. But how is this actually possible? My intuition is that as sample size goes up, the distribution narrows; but it's not like higher sampling actually *changes* the population SD. Why, then, is it the case that the higher the N, the lower the p-value?
[image]

In short, isn't it possible that two distributions could be sufficiently close to each other that they could, in principle, *never* be statistically significantly different from one another? This question has been killing me. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: The standard deviation might not depend on the sample size, but what about the standard error? (The terms are *not* synonymous.)

Comment: i think this may be my source of confusion. when doing a z- or a t-test, the two distributions you're comparing are the distributions of *sample means*. therefore it is standard errors (i.e., not standard deviations), and those will minimize with a larger N? does that sound correct? and furthermore, how do you get a distribution of sample means when, for instance, in an experiment, you only have ONE mean value per group. How can you create a distribution of means when you only have one value per group?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the distributions of the corresponding sample means. The sample means are $\overline{X}_{1/2}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{1,2},\sigma_{1,2}/\sqrt{N})$.

Therefore, the distribution of the sample means get narrower with increasing sample size N. At some sample size N, the two distributions of the sample meams become distinguishable.

If you want to construct a test and a p-value, I suggest looking into a permutation test (or a bit different a bootstrap test).

In the permutation test, you draw samples from both distributions and compute the difference of the means of two groups (the difference will on average be zero). At some big sample size you will observe that the original difference of means gets a low p-value.

However, if the sample size is not big enough, a small difference in means might stay unnoticed (due to too high p-values).

Comment: i think i was confused about the fact that the distributions compare sample means. but here is an outstanding question: when doing an experiment, for instance, you're only getting ONE mean for each group. How is a distribution created for sample means when there is only one mean collected?

Comment: Have a look at bootstraping